# How can I trigger a click event in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Here's the thing. 
I have a button in the child component and when I click the button it emits an event. I want to trigger it when the parent component is mounted, what should I do? Or is there another way to reach the goal?
PS:The button is generated by v-for in the child component.

Comment: can you add some code ?

Comment: You can manually invoke a listener inside `mounted` hook. Share some code if it doesn't help.

Comment: The listener needs some arguments from the child component. I don't think  the code's gonna help so I did not put it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your child component may look like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="child">
    <button @click="buttonClick">Button</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['buttonId'],
    methods:{
      buttonClick() {
        this.$emit('buttonClick', this.buttonId)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

And your parent component:

```
<template>
  <div class="parent">
    <child v-for="i in 5" :buttonId="i"></child>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Child from './Child.vue'

  export default {
    components: {
      Child,
    },
    methods: {
      onButtonClick(buttonId) {
        console.log('Got a click event from button ', buttonId)
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.$children.forEach(child => {
        child.buttonClick()
      })
    }
  }
</script>
```